# Drop dataframe rows with values that are an array of NaN

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a dataframe where in one column, I've ended up with some values that are not merely "NaN" but an array of NaNs (ie, "[nan, nan, nan]")

I want to change those values to 0. If it were simply "nan" I would use:

```
df.fillna(0)
```

But that doesn't work in this instance.

For instance if:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
         'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
         'Version':[1,1,2,2,1,2],
         'Cost':[17,np.nan,24,[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],13,8]})
```

Using df1.fillna(0) yields:

```
   ID  Version             Cost
0   1        1               17
1   2        1                0
2   3        2               24
3   4        2  [nan, nan, nan]
4   5        1               13
5   6        2                8
```

When I'd like to get the output:

```
   ID  Version             Cost
0   1        1               17
1   2        1                0
2   3        2               24
3   4        2                0
4   5        1               13
5   6        2                8
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: edited to provide one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case column `Cost` is an object so you can first convert to numeric and then `fillna`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":list(range(1,7)),
                   "Version":[1,1,2,2,1,2],
                   "Cost": [17,0,24,['nan', 'nan', 'nan'], 13, 8]})
```

Where `df.dtypes`

```sh
ID          int64
Version     int64
Cost       object
dtype: object
```

So you can convert this columns `to_numeric` using `errors='coerce'` which means that assign a np.nan if conversion is not possible.

```py
df["Cost"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Cost"], errors='coerce')\
               .fillna(0)
```

or if you prefer in two steps

```py
df["Cost"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Cost"], errors='coerce')
df["Cost"] = df["Cost"].fillna(0)
```